# rp2 missing libintl.9.dylib library

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed rp2 on ananconda (OSX).  I am getting the following error message when importing rp2:

from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libintl.9.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/martinlettau/anaconda/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
  Reason: image not found

Everything is updated (OSX Sierra 10.12.3, conda version : 4.2.13, python version : 2.7.13, Xcode 8.2.1).

I searched the harddrive but could not find libintl.9.dylib.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, currently I observe the same problem on my system.

Comment: Related? https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1614